# I want to create a custom web part with a button that will provision a new site based off a pre-designed site template

Tags: c#, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013

How do I connect the pre-designed site template to the create site class and then call that class in the button1_click event action?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
Server.Transfer("new site based of pre-designed site template", true);
}
```